# How to reset jquery fileupload template

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I have an app with jQuery.FileUpload and template for files in a modal dialog. I can upload just one file at a time.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1
});
```

After file uploading, I close modal dialog.

When I open the modal dialog again, the template is disabled, I can't add any files.
I want to reset template after closing the modal dialog. How can I do that?

Is there a method that reset it? "destroy" didn't help me.

Comment: Have you tried `.reset()`

Comment: `$('#fileupload').reset()` doesn't help

Comment: if you can give us your code it's easier to help.

Comment: I think this link will help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503856/fileupload-uploads-files-multiple-times